# HTML: Radio button displaying dropdown list or textfield based on selections

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, radio-button, textfield

Hi I would like to create a simple function where when the user click on the radio button value 'Yes' it will display a dropdown list, but when the user click No, it will display a textfield. Then, those values will be inserted to the database.

This is my radio button, dropdown list code and textfield code:

```html
<td>Principle Author / Member</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>SEC member?
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:check();" name="radiocheck" id="yes">Yes
  <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:check();" name="radiocheck" id="no">No
  <br />
  <div id="checkyes" name="checkyes" style="display:none;">
    <select name="p_author" id="p_author">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
      <option value="E">E</option>
      <option value="F">F</option>
      <option value="G">G</option>
      <option value="H">H</option>
      <option value="I">I</option>
      <option value="J">J</option>
      <option value="K">K</option>
      <option value="K">K</option>
      <option value="L">L</option>
      <option value="M">M</option>
      <option value="N">N</option>
      <option value="O">O</option>
      <option value="P">P</option>
      <option value="Q">Q</option>
      <option value="R">R</option>
      <option value="S">S</option>
      <option value="T">T</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="checkno" name="checkno" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="p_author" id="p_author" size="40" placeholder="Please enter here..">
  </div>
</td>
```

This is my Javascript code:

```js
function check() {
  if (document.getElementById('yes').checked) {
    document.getElementById('checkyes').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('checkno').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('checkyes').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('checkno').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

It works before, I'm able to insert the value (for both dropdown and textfield) to the database but now when I recheck and try to insert the dropdown value to the database, it doesn't work. I can only insert the textfield value. I have made changes here and there but still could not make it work. Can someone please point out what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the select and input with the same **name** and **id**, your database is saving the input text value always because it is the last field sent, if you send it via GET you have

```
your_page?radiocheck=on&p_author=B&p_author=text
```

You should change the names and ids i.e

```
<select name="p_author1" id="p_author1">
...
</select>

...

<input type="text" name="p_author2" id="p_author2" size="40" placeholder="Please enter here..">
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried your solution and it works. Thanks! :) But i'm just wondering if it's possible to set this as the same name & id and store this two values inside the same column, for example, author. Just want to know

Comment: @Azie if you are using MySQL database, you could store two values separated by one character, like "-", i.e "B-other author",taking advantage of "implode()" and "explode()" functions to read and write in your DB

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that once the object is hidden, it is not being passed along with the form submits.

What I suggest is a running list of hidden fields.  Drop the values into those fields before you submit your form.  Then you'll always have all the information.  Whether you choose to use it when you process the form in PHP is up to you.